# Can`t bind entry and property in two way mode

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Try to create simple app that will add items to the list. Have problems with binding entries with properties in ViewModel.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyScoreDemo.ViewModels;assembly=MyScoreDemo"
         x:Class="MyScoreDemo.Views.ClubListPage">
<StackLayout
    Padding="15"
    Spacing="10">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry x:Name="EntryName" Text="{Binding Club.Name, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Label Text="Country:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Entry x:Name="EntryCountry" Text="{Binding Club.Country, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference EntryName}"
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" />

    </Grid>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clubs}"
              Margin="5">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Country}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ClubListViewModel/>
    </StackLayout.BindingContext>

</StackLayout>
```

And ViewModel code:

```
private Club _club;
    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; }

    public ClubListViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new Command(AddClub);
        RemoveCommand = new Command(RemoveClub);
        Clubs = new ObservableCollection<Club>();
    }

    public Club Club
    {
        get => _club;
        set
        {
            _club = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Club");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    //Commands
    private void AddClub()
    {
    }
```

Set breakpoints in property`s Club set section and try different modes, but it never stops.

Comment: where's `DataContext`?

Comment: In question there is part of xaml. Data Context is in the end of xaml file.

Comment: can you paste that part? because `DataContext` is important

Answer (score 0):

All that I need to change is ta add `Club = new Club();` in constructor of my ViewModel class.